# DESCRIBE TABLE equivalent in CockroachDB?

Tags: cockroachdb

I tried using Oracle's `DESCRIBE TABLE...` statement in CockroachDB and got a syntax error. What’s the equivalent command?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In CockroachDB, the [`SHOW COLUMNS`](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/show-columns.html) statement returns information about the columns in a table, similar to the `DESCRIBE` statement in MySQL and the `\d` command in PostgreSQL:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM tablename;
```

You can also get some information by running [`SHOW INDEX`](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/show-index.html) or [`SHOW CREATE TABLE`](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/show-create-table.html) or by querying the [`information_schema` database](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/information-schema.html).